# Remove mutually exclusive records

Tags: python, dictionary

What would be the fastest way to remove mutually exclusive record in the record set.
I'm using Python and can leverage Pandas if needed.

I have following data:

| Record ID | Shared On (UNIX timestamp) | Share type | Share To User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1611872850 | shared | user A |
| 2 | 1611872851 | shared | user B |
| 3 | 1611872852 | shared | user B |
| 1 | 1611872853 | share_removed | user A |
| 3 | 1611872854 | share_removed | user B |
| 4 | 1611872855 | shared | user C |
| 1 | 1611872856 | shared | user A |
| 2 | 1611872857 | share_removed | user B |
| 1 | 1611872858 | share_removed | user A |

As we see that for example, record 1 was shared to user A, then removed from User A, then shared again, and then removed, hence no records should exist.

Output should be only one row:

| Record ID | Shared On | Share type | Share To User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1611872855 | shared | user C |

One option is to use a dictionary and then remove the record if mutually exclusive record with they key and share type exist in the record. Key might be something like `[recordId]-[shareType]-[sharedToUser]`

I was thinking maybe there is similar functionality already exists somewhere (in Pandas?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following -

1. Define a new column `state` that equals 1 if `shared` and -1 if `share_removed`
2. Groupby RecordID and UserID and take a sum over this new variable.

   - If a user has their access removed then the sum would be 0 (or less that 0 incase its removed multiple times)
   - If a user has their access still there, then the sum would be 1 or above (incase shared multiple times)
3. Create a new column by this condition and then use that to finally filter your dataframe. Drop the condition column if necessary

```
#Check state of access as 1 or -1
df['state'] = df['Share type'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='shared' else -1)

#Groupby and filter for rows with state >=1
df[df.groupby(['Record ID', 'Share To User'])['state'].transform(sum)>=1].drop('state', axis=1)
```

[image]

---

**Alternative:**

If you are open to using `numpy.where`, this makes it much cleaner because then you can use `df.assign` without having to explicitly create new columns for groupby -

```
cond = df.assign(state = lambda x: np.where(x['Share type']=='shared', 1, -1))\
         .groupby(['Record ID','Share To User'])['state']\
         .transform(sum)>=1

df[cond]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
>>> d = df.set_index('Record ID')
>>> d[(d.groupby(by='Record ID')['Share type'].count() % 2).astype(bool)]
            Shared On Share type Share To User
Record ID                                     
4          1611872855     shared        user C
```

Such approach only works if the two possible **Share type** events, i.e. `'share'` and `'share_removed'`, are *forced* to be mutually exclusive -- like a on-off switch.

Otherwise, if for some reason, either a `'shared'` or a `'share_removed'` event is not reported, then my approach is not as robust as @Akshay's.

Comment: I was thinking about this approach as well, but issue is that if there are multiple records that point to share_remove for same record and user (or for share) then this fails. But otherwise a clean approach.

Comment: Sorry @AkshaySehgal you may be right but I do not see what you mean exactly ?

Comment: So, imagine a scenario that there is 1 row that says user A has access to record 1.. and 2 rows that say user A has their access removed to record 1.

Comment: Unless you explicitly remove duplicates rows from the table, the %2 may fail but its just a scenario that might not occur atall.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Yes I had this possibility in mind and I assumed that this cannot occur at all since the `share` and `share_removed` "events" are said to be mutually exclusive. Like a on-off switch. Otherwise, you are indeed right !